# SQL find string plus option char

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to find a string that match to the following

```
989X1[OPTIONAL[a-z]]
```

This is i tried :

```
... where x LIKE '989X1[a-z]?'
... where x LIKE '989X1[a-z]'
```

but the first query match also "`989X10a`",
the other one don't match `989X1` without the optional string.

With kind regards
F Harmsen

Comment: use like this  where x LIKE '989X1%'

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR, will pass other trailing characters than a-z as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can get using `LIKE` would be to use an underscore:

```
where x = '989X1' OR x LIKE '989X1_'
```

But this would match *any* single character, not just alphabets.  Instead, you get closer with `REGEXP`:

```
where x REGEXP '989X1[a-z]?'   -- or REGEXP '^989X1[a-z]?$' for an exact match
```

Even with `REGEXP` it is not exact, because `REGEXP` is case insensitive, therefore so is the range.